# JQuery selecctor of the input card element from stripe not getting any result

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

Im trying to add a small card display plugin to a stripe form generated with the Card() element. However Im not being able to get the jquery selector to get the input. I suspect that the input has not been added to the DOM yet at the time of my `console.log()`

Here is my code:

```
   var card = elements.create('card', { style: style } );

    // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
    card.mount('#card-element');

    card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      if (event.error) {
        displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
      } else {
        displayError.textContent = '';
      }
    });

    card.on('ready', function(){
        console.log('The input', $('input[name="cardnumber"'));
        $('form').card({
            // a selector or DOM element for the container
            // where you want the card to appear
            container: '.card-wrapper', // *required*
            formSelectors: {
                numberInput: 'input[name="cardnumber"]', // optional — default input[name="number"]
                // expiryInput: 'input[name="expdate"]', // optional — default input[name="expiry"]
                // cvcInput: 'input[name="cvc"]', // optional — default input[name="cvc"]
                // nameInput: 'input[name="name"]' // optional - defaults input[name="name"]
            },
            placeholders: {
                name: 'Cliente Chopinmol',
                expiry: 'expdate',
                cvc: 'cvc'
            }
            // all of the other options from above
        });
    })
```

When the line `console.log('The input', $('input[name="cardnumber"'));` executes there is no input element on the selector, even though I can see it on my browser's HTML.

Can anyone tell me whats the event/callback I have to user in order guarantee that the element is on the DOM when I call jQuery?

Thank you

Comment: It looks like the command following your `console.log` is what actually creates the `<input>`. - quote: "a selector [...] where you want the card to appear"

Comment: You are right! But the problem is still there since I tried `document.getElementsByName("cardnumber")` and I still get an empty list, although I have this element on my html:  `<input type="tel" autocomplete="cc-number" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" name="cardnumber" class="InputElement is-empty" aria-label="Credit or debit card number" placeholder="Número de tarjeta" aria-placeholder="Número de tarjeta" aria-invalid="false" value="">`

Comment: Problem "solved": your selector is missing the `]` at the end. Just use `input[name=cardnumber]`. However, stripe includes an `<iframe>`, and the entire stripe form is in there, inaccessible to your script, unfortunately.